# Functions in derived class not being able to access members in base class

Tags: c++, c++17

```cpp
#include <memory>
template<typename T> struct vector_base{
    std::allocator<T> alloc;
    T *elem;
    int sz;
    int space;
    vector_base(const std::allocator<T> &a, int n):alloc{a},elem{alloc.allocate(n)},sz{n},space{n}{}
    ~vector_base(){alloc.deallocate(elem,space);}
};
template<typename T> class vector:private vector_base<T> {
public:
    vector():sz{0},elem{nullptr},space{0}{}
    explicit vector(int s):sz{s},elem{new T[s]}, space{s}{
        for(int i = 0; i<sz; i++) elem[i]=0;
    }
    T &at(int n);
    const T &at(int n) const;
    void reserve(int newalloc);
    void resize(int newsize, T def=T());
    int capacity() const { return space;}
    void push_back(int d);
    vector &operator=(const vector &a);
};
```

EDIT: Here is the compilation log

```
prog.cpp: In constructor ‘vector<T>::vector()’:
prog.cpp:12:14: error: class ‘vector<T>’ does not have any field named ‘sz’
     vector():sz{0},elem{nullptr},space{0}{}
              ^~
prog.cpp:12:20: error: class ‘vector<T>’ does not have any field named ‘elem’
     vector():sz{0},elem{nullptr},space{0}{}
                    ^~~~
prog.cpp:12:34: error: class ‘vector<T>’ does not have any field named ‘space’
     vector():sz{0},elem{nullptr},space{0}{}
                                  ^~~~~
prog.cpp: In constructor ‘vector<T>::vector(int)’:
prog.cpp:13:28: error: class ‘vector<T>’ does not have any field named ‘sz’
     explicit vector(int s):sz{s},elem{new T[s]}, space{s}{
                            ^~
prog.cpp:13:34: error: class ‘vector<T>’ does not have any field named ‘elem’
     explicit vector(int s):sz{s},elem{new T[s]}, space{s}{
                                  ^~~~
prog.cpp:13:50: error: class ‘vector<T>’ does not have any field named ‘space’
     explicit vector(int s):sz{s},elem{new T[s]}, space{s}{
                                                  ^~~~~
prog.cpp:14:26: error: ‘sz’ was not declared in this scope
         for(int i = 0; i<sz; i++) elem[i]=0;
                          ^~
prog.cpp:14:26: note: suggested alternative: ‘s’
         for(int i = 0; i<sz; i++) elem[i]=0;
                          ^~
                          s
prog.cpp:14:35: error: ‘elem’ was not declared in this scope
         for(int i = 0; i<sz; i++) elem[i]=0;
                                   ^~~~
prog.cpp:14:35: note: suggested alternative: ‘enum’
         for(int i = 0; i<sz; i++) elem[i]=0;
                                   ^~~~
                                   enum
prog.cpp: In member function ‘int vector<T>::capacity() const’:
prog.cpp:20:35: error: ‘space’ was not declared in this scope
     int capacity() const { return space;}
                                   ^~~~~
```

After a little bit of poking around, I think my problem here is that I need to somehow call the base constructor and find a way to let the functions in `class vector` to access the members in `struct vector_base`.

How I am supposed to do that, I have entirely no idea.

Comment: when you get a compiler error you should include it in the quesiton.

Comment: Your C++ textbook should explain how to invoke the base class's constructor from a derived class's constructor. This is one of the first, basic things that's described when inheritance is explained. Is there something in your textbook's explanation that's unclear to you?

Comment: You can't initialize inherited members in a derived constructor.

Comment: oh, yeah adding a default constructor might work...

Comment: Virtual base class members notwithstanding (and they don't apply here anyway), the only things that should appear in an initialization list of a ctor are (1) the base class ctor if applicable (and it is here), and (2) the instance variables of the class (not the base; those are handled in the base-class initialization list), preferably in order of declaration within the class (because that's the order they'll be initialized anyway, so you may as well make that crystal clear in the code presentation).

Comment: Find another name for the derived class, don't use  vector at it's an STL container

Comment: I guess you have a classic [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) here

Comment: Also, when the base is a template, you need to help the compiler by accessing inherited members through `this->`. And your idea to "bypass" the `allocator` of the base class (which I guess you're attempting) is not going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not initialize the members of the base class directly, it would contradict any sense of class encapsulation. That's why you wrote constructors in the base class, you can invoke those like:

```
template<typename T> class vector:private vector_base<T> {
public:
    std::allocator<T> myalloc;
    vector() : vector_base<T>(myalloc, 0) {
    }
```

Of course I wonder why you have only that kind of constructor. You questions is quite convoluted, and private inheritance is almost never what you want. Also your questions seems to be incomplete.

Comment: well actually, this is from Bjarne's PPP page 687, maybe I understood what he wanted to tell me incorrectly.

Comment: You can access them but not initialize them, meaning no usage in the list initialization, and you have to run the constructor of your base first.